# OWL API- how to add new classes, properties, individuals, to OWL file?

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api

I want to add a new class, properties to the OWL file which is created from protege. I need to update the owl file. This is the code that i have tried to add a class. But it doesnot updated the original OWL file. Only the output of netbeans IDE provide the updated OWL file.

```
 OWLDataFactory df = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();

 OWLEntity entity = df.getOWLEntity(EntityType.CLASS, IRI.create("#newclass"));

 OWLAxiom declare = df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(entity);
 manager.addAxiom(ontology,declare );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an OWL storer object:

```
AbstractOWLStorer storer = new FunctionalSyntaxStorer();
```

Here I am creating a storer that will store the ontology in functional syntax format. You can use a different constructor for different format (XML, etc.).

```
storer.storeOntology(ontology, new FileDoumentTarget(new File(filePath)), new FunctionalSyntaxDocumentFormat());
```

For more specific details about the format you want to store the ontology, check the docs online:
http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4_0_2/org/semanticweb/owlapi/util/AbstractOWLStorer.html

Comment: thnks Ammar. As i'm new to Ontology, I cannot update the OWL file.  as i wanted, If u know pls help me. I need to add new classes, properties etc.

Comment: I don't recommend this method - as the code shown already has a manager, and the ontology was loaded form a file, all that's needed is to call `manager.saveOntology(ontology);`

Comment: Yes , I hv alredy called,  manager.saveOntology(ontology, format, documentTarget);

Comment: Anyone knows how to add object properties, data properties and relationships between classes to an owl file using owlapi? I dnt have idea about it

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually save the ontology back to the file. Use

```
manager.saveOntology(ontology);
```

to achieve that.